# react await doensn't wait when using onSubmit instead of onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In my login-page, I wanted to make ENTER key presses work apart from just clicking the "login" button, so I made the button be of type "submit" and give the form the method "onSubmit" as shown below:

```
<Button onClick={(event) => this.handleLogin(event)}>{loginTextElement}</Button>
```

to

```
<Button type="submit">{loginTextElement}</Button>
```

I also have this instead now:

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleLogin(event)}>
```

However I have found that my method handleLogin that looks like this:

```
const signedIn = await API.authenticate(this.state.email, this.state.password);

alert("this is displayed immidiately with onSubmit, but with onClick it waits until signedIn is set")

if(signedIn==API.constants.ADMIN || signedIn==API.constants.CUSTOMER){
    console.log("signedin was admin or customer")
    this.setState({signedIn: signedIn})
}else{
    this.setState({loginPressed:false, showError:true})
}
```

no longer waits for the const signedIn to be set, and proceeds with the code anyway, which is causing some really weird behaviour and one cannot login.

Comment: Not sure if it'll fix the issue, but maybe you could try doing `event.preventDefault()` in `handleLogin`? The form submit event might be doing some funky stuff

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `this.handleLogin`, you need to prevent default behaviour on form submitting, which is POSTing the data. Try this in `handleLogin`:

```
event.preventDefault();
```